# insert two table with different column, Is it possible? android studio

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

Is it possible to add two table at one goes?
When I click button the code will run this

```
try {
                    SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Donation_Page.this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                    int i = app_preferences.getInt("key", 0);
                    i = ++i;
                    txn.setTxnNo(i + "");
                    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    cv.put("name", txn.getName());
                    //cv.put("TxnNo", txn.getTxnNo());
                    cv.put("TxnNo", String.format("%04d", i));
                    cv.put("TxnDate", txn.getTxnDate());
                    cv.put("Amount", txn.getAmount().toPlainString());
                    cv.put("Description1", txn.getDescription1());
                    cv.put("Description2", txn.getDescription2());
                    editor.putInt("key", i).commit();
                    db.insert("Donation_Details", null, cv);

                    db.close();
                    Toast.makeText(Donation_Page.this, "Add successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

The above code will store into one table which is "Donation_Details". But I still have one more table is "Information" which has one column is "Last txn no". I also want to `cv.put` it. But it's in the "Information" table, not in the "Donation_Details". and `db.insert("Donation_Details", null, cv);` can only write one time. So how do I add one more table inside? is it possible?

**Here is my Update**

After put this line of code. there is an error shows `getLastTxnNo() in SettingModel cannot be applied to java. lang. String`

```
try {

                    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    cv.put("name", txn.getName());
                    cv.put("TxnDate", txn.getTxnDate());
                    cv.put("Amount", txn.getAmount().toPlainString());
                    cv.put("Description1", txn.getDescription1());
                    cv.put("Description2", txn.getDescription2());
                    db.insert("Donation_Details", null, cv);
                    db.close();

                    SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Donation_Page.this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                    int i = app_preferences.getInt("key", 0);
                    i = ++i;
                    txnSec.getLastTxnNo(i + "");
                    SQLiteDatabase dbSec = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues cvSec = new ContentValues();
                    cvSec.put("TxnNo", String.format("%04d", i));
                    editor.putInt("key", i).commit();
                    dbSec.insert("Information", null, cvSec);
                    dbSec.close();

                    Toast.makeText(Donation_Page.this, "Add successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

the error shows at the line of "`txnSec.getLastTxnNo(i + "");`" But whether this is String or Int also can be applied, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the relationship between `Donation_Details` table and `Information` table if have any.
Second, "So how do I add one more table inside?" not clear.

My suggestion, Please create another new `SQLiteDatabase` object as below and try the rest.

```
SQLiteDatabase dbNew = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cvNew = new ContentValues();
cvNew.put("Last txn no", txn.getTxnNo());
dbNew.insert("Information", null, cvNew);

dbNew.close();
```

Please update `cvNew.put("Last txn no", txn.getTxnNo());` this line according to your requirement.

Thank you.

Comment: friend, I've update my code, there is an error at the line of code, Could you see what's the problem?

Comment: There is no relationship between my two tables, there's something I just want to store.

Comment: I've updated my question, I put my error there.  `getLastTxnNo() in SettingModel cannot be applied to java. lang. String` You can check it.

Comment: Hi Please check what is the parameter type for `txnSec.getLastTxnNo(INT or STRING)` now you are parsing a string.

Comment: Ohhh... I know already. I should write setLastTxnNo instead of getLastTxnNo. Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

You have to make two calls, but if you want the tables to update at the same time, put them inside a transaction.